# Github Actions + Slack API invalid_blocks

Tags: curl, github-actions, slack-api, slack-block-kit, chatops

The following configuration (indented for readability) returns the `invalid_blocks` error. However, it works in the Block Kit Builder.

```
  - name: Notify
    run: >-
      curl -X POST "${{ secrets.WEBHOOK }}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data
      '{
        "blocks": [
          {
            "type": "header",
            "text": {
              "type": "plain_text",
              "text": "New configs were successfully built and uploaded",
              "emoji": true
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "${{ env.CONFIGS }}"
            }
          }
        ]
      }'
```

The configs are the `STDOUT` from a docker run command earlier in the workflow.

I have a working legacy configuration.

```
    - name: Notify
      run: >-
      curl -X POST "${{ secrets.WEBHOOK }}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data
      '{"attachments":[
          { "mrkdwn_in":["text"],
            "pretext":"New configs were successfully built and uploaded",
            "text":"${{ env.CONFIGS }}",
            "color":"good"}]}'
```

I don't understand why it wouldn't work. Other solutions I've seen involve sending the json payload as a referenced external file, which I don't think would work here. My guess is that there's something about Github Actions that doesn't work well with the Slack API [Layout Blocks](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks), which is recommended over the legacy [Secondary Attachments](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/attachments) format. Anyone else encountering this issue?

Comment: Does the command work when run from the command line?

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, I can confirm the command does work as expected from the command line but is still returning `invalid_blocks` when ran as part of a GHA workflow